# Getting BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 in Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

In My Activity it  Checks the user credentials and returns session id and related info if valid. The Method is POST.The parameter has to send as JSON.

```
{
"params": {
    "context": {},
    "db": "testing",
    "login": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
    }
}
```

So i create a JSONObject and send it as it is With Header.I am getting response in POSTMAN.But what i m getting error when i call it as it is.Can Any one help me in this?

```
 private void volleyLogin() throws JSONException {
        mProgressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        JSONObject one = new JSONObject();
        one.put("context",new JSONObject());
        one.put("db","testing");
        one.put("login","admin");
        one.put("password","admin");
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        params.put("params",one);
        HashMap<String, String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();
        header.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                ApiConstants.URL_AUTHENTICATE,params,header, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
             System.out.println("Response"+response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.println("VolleyError"+error);

                    }
                }

        );
        jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(120),
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        System.out.println("jsObjRequest"+jsObjRequest);
        requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
    }
```

Here is the Custom Request Class

```
public class CustomRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener;

    private JSONObject jsonObjectParams;
    private Map<String, String> headers;

    public CustomRequest(int method,String url, JSONObject jsonObjectParams,Map<String, String> headers,
                         Response.Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.jsonObjectParams = jsonObjectParams;
        this.headers= headers;
        System.out.println("method"+method);
        System.out.println("url"+url);
        System.out.println("jsonObjectParams"+jsonObjectParams);


    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return headers;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {

        if(volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null){
            VolleyError error = new VolleyError(new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data));
            volleyError = error;
        }
        return volleyError;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

Create a singletone class VolleyDispatcher, that holds the RequestQueue from volley.

```
public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (requestQueue == null) {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext.getApplicationContext());
    }

    return requestQueue;
}

/**
 * Recreates the request queue using username/password https auth.
 */
public void recreateRequestQueue() {
    if (!AppUtil.isEmpty(AppConstants.USERNAME) && !AppUtil.isEmpty(AppConstants.PASSWORD)) {//check if a user is logged in so that the https auth can be created if necessary
        if (requestQueue != null) {
            requestQueue.stop();
            requestQueue = null;
        }

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext.getApplicationContext(), new HurlCustomStack());
    }

}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
```

Call recreateRequestQueue before doing any volley requests

Implement the custom HurlStack

```
public class HurlCustomStack extends HurlStack {

    @Override
    protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
        // Workaround for the M release HttpURLConnection not observing the
        // HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects() property.
        // https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194495
//      connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(HttpURLConnection.getFollowRedirects());

        return HttpUrlConnectionHelper.getInstance().createHttpUrlConnection(url);
    }
}
```

And the client creation method:

```
public HttpURLConnection createHttpUrlConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Create http url connection with url : " + url.toString());

        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = null;
        if ("https".equalsIgnoreCase(url.getProtocol())) {
            HttpsURLConnection https = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            https.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
            httpConnection = https;
        } else {
            httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        }

        httpConnection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);
        httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode((AppConstants.USERNAME + ":" + AppConstants.PASSWORD).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());

        return httpConnection;
    }
```

So now, every time you want to make a request, just use the `addToRequestQueue` method in the `VolleyDispatcher` class.